# Cassandra as a service

Tags: cassandra

Are there any cassandra as a service providers you are aware of. I found cassandra.io, but they offer really big starter packages. Do you know any other?

Comment: which provider did you end up using? We are also looking for a similar service. can you pls share your experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[www.instaclustr.com](https://www.instaclustr.com/) was announced earlier this year. I haven't tried it myself, but it looks interesting.

Comment: Prices start at $400/month :( https://www.instaclustr.com/pricing

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately NoSQL solutions don't have too much service providers at this moment, I was searching NoSQL service providers several weeks ago and I'd just found a few ones.

I don't know any Cassandra service provider at the moment but I found a MongoDB provider called MongoHQ (https://mongohq.com/) that it seemed to work seriously. I guess that they have an available free tier but, as I said, I had a look a few weeks ago and I'm not sure.

I don't know if you were looking for a NoSQL general solution or only a Cassandra provider but I hope it helps.